# Cole-Hopf transformation, getting rid of constant with boundary conditions at infinity

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I am asked to show that the transformation \begin{equation} u=-2\mu\partial_x\log\phi \end{equation} brings the viscous Burgers equation

\begin{equation} \partial_tu+u\partial_xu=\mu\partial_{xx}u \end{equation} to the heat equation
\begin{equation} \partial_t\phi=\mu\partial_{xx}\phi \end{equation} given that \begin{equation} u\rightarrow0\text{ as }|x|\rightarrow\infty\end{equation}

I can show that the transformation gives me the equation
\begin{equation} \partial_t\phi=\mu\partial_{xx}\phi -\frac{\phi}{2\mu}\psi(t)\end{equation}

where $\psi(t)$ is the 'constant' from integration over $x$, but I am struggling to get rid of that last term. Every other proof/answered question I have seen has finite boundary conditions so I am not really sure how to make use of this infinite boundary condition.

Comment: Why not do the usual trick of redefining $\phi$ to be $\phi\exp(-\int \psi(t)dt)$? The boundary condition simply assures that this is well defined.

Comment: The boundary conditions are irrelevant! The crux is that $\phi$ is not uniquely determined by the given formula, and you do have to pick the *correct* $\phi$ in order for it to satisfy the heat equation. And the way to do it is to first choose *some* $\phi$, and then adjust it, as described in the comment by Andrew McMillan above, and in the deleted answer by Calvin Khor (which should have been accepted).